# Returning data from php called via jQuery (ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble returning data from a php page.

```
test = function(data){
    alert(data);
}

newContent = function(var1){
  $.ajax({
      url: 'path/to/item.php&var1='+var1,
      success: function(data){
        test(data);
      }
  });
}
```

Which should return "Success" via `echo 'Success!';` on the `item.php` page.

Why is it returning undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is incorrect:

```
url: 'path/to/item.php&var1='+var1,
```

Use this instead:

```
url: 'path/to/item.php?var1='+var1,
```

[**JsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qjYLw/)

Comment: Nevermind, I just learned about [echos in jsFiddle](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your `item.php` file, you need to echo the result.  Something like this:

```
echo $data;
```

rather than:

```
return $data;
```

Comment: It is echo, as stated in OP. True return will not work for the ajax.